# How to combine several option in sed -e command?

Tags: sed

Today I spent a day trying to do the following.

Let's say I have a file of Fortran code.

I want to change everything in this file to lower case.
But if a line starts with a specific character or word, this line should not be changed.

For example, the following command

```
sed -i -e '/^!/! s/\(.*\)/\L\1/' $filein
```

does what I want, it does change everything to lower case, omitting comments (lines started with "!") or

```
sed -i -e '/^#include/! s/\(.*\)/\L\1/' $filein
```

omits lines starting with "#include" word.

Question: how to combine those two commands into one?

So basically I need to add "or" under the first condition.
I have tried multiply options without any luck. I guess it should be something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OR `\|`:

Given a file:

```
!FOO
BAR
BAZ
# COMMENT
```

Command

```
sed -e '/^!\|^#/!s/\(.*\)/\L\1/' $filein
```

Output

```
!FOO
bar
baz
# COMMENT
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @MikhailModestov Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. That's a way of saying thanks here at Stack networks.

Answer (score 0):

to do

```
sed -i -e "$exp1" "$file"
sed -i -e "$exp2" "$file"
```

you can do

```
sed -i -e "$exp1" -e "$exp2" "$file"
```